# How about this 20MB json response performance?

Tags: django, postgresql, performance, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a API build in django, it goes to query data with PostgreSQL and serializer to json.

Now, this API content-length is 3MB (I use the gzip, the truely size is 20MB) response time cost me about 10~20 seconds.

I want to ask, Is this performance is right? there is any optimization space that I can do?

Comment: We can't see what you're doing, so based on the little information you've provided, you have a couple of options: 1) Reduce the amount of data you're returning from your query. 2) Split the results into multiple responses that don't take as long to compress and transmit. 3) Reduce the amount of data you're returning. 4) Did I mention reducing the amount of data you're returning yet? :-)

Comment: If it takes 10-20 seconds, it sounds more like poor API design, however I don't know your use-case so I can't be sure.
Check if you can do any of the recommendations of Ken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it takes 10-20 seconds, it sounds more like poor API design, however I don't know your use-case so I can't be sure.

Check if you can do any of the recommendations of Ken. Here are some more ideas:

- [Pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) is a great way to split data - if your data can be split into logical parts, DRF has a great number of ways to paginate querysets.
- Using the right gzip compression level could be a factor, given the size of your data. Read more about it [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/253074/what-is-the-best-nginx-compression-gzip-level)
- See if you can use `etag` option, where the server sends a 304 Not Modified if the API response has not changed between two consecutive calls to the API. [DRF does not support etags](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/32) out-of-the-box AFAIK, so you will have to find a [work-around](https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/).
- Since you mentioned "real-time" data, I am assuming there's some concept of streaming of temporal data. There are interesting ways to do combine [client caching](http://www.apiacademy.co/how-to-http-caching-for-restful-hypermedia-apis/) + [cursor based](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/cursoring.html) pagination to only send the 'new data' you can explore. This only works if the two preconditions are met: The changes to your API are incremental and temporal in nature.

Comment: Maybe "etag" is not suit on me, because My data is real-time iot data, just in case the data maybe has changed.

Comment: I can't do pagination, I guess. because my front-end proposal need this data to surface on the map, so maybe pagination is not a good way to me?

Comment: @FrankLiou etags wont "always" cache, you can control it based on whether the data changed. It might still be beneficial - please do some reading to see if it suits your usecase

Comment: Sure, happy to help. Let me if any of the techniques work for you :)